# Apache not detecting /web/ folder in my <script> tags

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, vhosts

Running Symfony 2.8, PHP 5.6.

I've been trying to configure a repo on another laptop, and I think that I'm close, but I am having an issue with Apache not detecting the proper root directory.

When I visit my chosen URL, I know it's loading from my repo because it's using the favicon and it's loading my `offline.html` page. However, it can't locate this file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/vue/prod/bundle.js"></script>`

It's returning me a 404. The error is trying to find this:

`http://my.link.co.uk/vue/prod/bundle.js`

That file is in my directory but under `/web/`. This is the config for my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin <MY EMAIL ADDRESS>
    DocumentRoot "/PATH/PATH/PATH/REPO/web"
    ServerName my.link.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.my.link.co.uk
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /PATH/PATH/PATH/SSL/certName.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /PATH/PATH/PATH/SSL/key.key
    ErrorLog "error log path that is just producing an empty file"

    <Directory "/PATH/PATH/PATH/REPO/web"">
      AllowOverride All
      Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Have I set up the VH incorrectly?

Comment: `my.link.co.uk != www.serverName.serverName.co.uk`

Comment: The setup is for clientname.mainUrl.co.uk